# Bootable flag doesn't change to "on"

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, system-installation, raid

Installing Server 14.04 and configuring software RAID-1. I already made my swap partition on my first HDD, and when i configure the remaining FREE SPACE, the option for "Bootable flag:" is present but remains "off" even when I hit enter.

Every time I try to change it, it briefly flashes a window that says "Computing the new state of the partition table" then returns to the Partition disks screen, with the Bootable flag still set to "off."

How can I set the bootable flag to "on?"

Comment: Chances are you don't need it. What partition table does your disk use -- MBR (called "ms-dos" by some tools) or GPT? Also, what tool are you using to try to change the boot flag?

Comment: @RodSmith I am using this walkthrough: https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html
There was also no option to choose "Primary" as it indicates to do in Step 4, if that helps.

Comment: Just a guess, but you may be booting in EFI/UEFI mode, in which case you'd be using GPT, on which there's no such thing as a primary partition (although some tools call all GPT partitions "primary"). On GPT, you should not set the "boot flag" on anything but the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition). I've only skimmed the procedure to which you link, but I don't think there's any need for a boot flag with that procedure, even when using MBR. Type `sudo parted /dev/sda print | grep Table` to determine your partition table type with certainty.

Comment: Just as an information for people who stumble about this: This is a pretty old bug of the debian-installer ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/477167 ) since Ubuntu 9.10 at least. So far it is still present in 16.04 (maybe newer versions as well). I _think_ that modern setups doesn't rely on the boot flag anymore anyway but I'm not sure about it and nevertheless it's still a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but I am still installing Ubuntu Server 14.04 and have found this issue as well. As far as I can tell it is from booting with EFI/UEFI media, as Rod Smith has stated.

I ran the install using a USB jump drive with the Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 ISO and the intention of installing in BIOS mode. In the BIOS menu I selected to boot from USB. The install ran normally and I created the partitions as desired (using 500mb ext2 in raid1 for the /boot partition) but I could not change the boot flag. Also, the partitioner did not ask for primary/logical partitions. The installer ran until the GRUB install, then failed. I attempted this multiple times with install variations with the same result.

Next I ran the install from a CD with the same ISO. I set up the partitions the same way and was able to set the bootable flag to on and also select primary/logical. The install then worked as expected and the GRUB install worked with complaint.

I am still new to installing and have not figured out all the details of BIOS/UEFI, but as far as I can tell this is where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

The same was for me. The difference was indeed it was a difference between uefi and BIOS.
My fix was to add a 3rd partition of 400mb and make that an EFI partition. After this the installation succeeded.